# Generalization of energy of geodesic

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, curvature, ricci-flow

As we know , a  curve $\gamma$ is geodesic iff $\nabla_\dot{\gamma}\dot{\gamma}=0$. The energy of curve is defined 
$$
E(t)=\frac{1}{2}\int |\dot{\gamma}|^2
$$
I don't know why define the energy so. I just think it is for the monotonicity in [heat flow](http://gen.lib.rus.ec/scimag/index.php?s=Closed%20geodesics%20on%20Riemannian%20manifolds%20via%20the%20heat%20flow&journalid=&v=&i=&p=&redirect=1) .

So I want to define suitable energy of other curve for monotonicity.For example, we consider the curve such that 
$$
\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}}\dot{\gamma}+Ric(\dot{\gamma},\cdot)=0
$$
then how to define a suitable energy such that in evolving equation
$$
\partial_tu(\theta,t)=\nabla_{u_\theta}u_\theta+Ric(u_\theta,\cdot)
$$
the energy is monotonicity ? $\theta$ is the parameter of curve, $t$ is the time in evolving equation. I think no matter how define the energy , not always ,we can get the monotonicity. It is needed  adding some condition of curvature.

Comment: Maybe the proper equation should be $$\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}} \dot{\gamma} \, + \, g^{-1} \text{Ric}(\dot{\gamma}, \cdot) = 0\, $$ where $g : TM \to T^*M$ is the isomorphism induced by the metric tensor. $\text{Ric}(\dot{\gamma}, \cdot)$ is a dual vector, not a tangent vector.

Comment: @Futurologist  Yes, I just write it as Cao and Zhu's paper.

Comment: The energy density of a curve is its kinetic energy up to constant $m$ (mass). i. e. $E(\gamma)=1/2 mv^2$. A generalized energy function is Dirichlet energy.